# How to progressively draw any line using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw lines progressively (currently using recursive functions) in a canvas element, and I'm able to successfully draw pairs of lines that are parallel to the x or y axes, this way:

```
function line(xa, ya, xb, yb) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(xa, ya);
    context.lineTo(xb, yb);
    context.stroke();
}

(function drawLine(i){
    line(155, i, 155, i-2);
    line(245, i, 245, i-2);
    if (i > 35) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            drawLine(i-2);
        }, 10);
    }
})(57);
```

And I get this:

[image]

(`context.lineWidth` is set to `10` and `context.lineCap` is set to `round`)

However, I've tried several ways of drawing pairs of lines that aren't strictly horizontal nor vertical but I'm only able to get something like this:

```
(function drawLine(i){
    line(155, i, 155+(57-i)/2, i-2);
    line(245, i, 245-(57-i)/2, i-2);
    if (i > 35) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            drawLine(i-2);
        }, 10);
    }
})(57);
```

[image]

(changing the value of `context.lineWidth` or `context.lineCap` doesn't solve the problem)

Is there a way to draw any kind of line progressively in a canvas element?

Comment: Maybe these two links are a good start: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480506/how-to-progressively-draw-line-animation-in-html5-canvas
- https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/

Comment: Is the line going to be straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version, you draw lines from a point based on the current value of `i` to a point based on the value of `i` in the next iteration. But in the second version, the `x` value of your start point is a constant. Base the start point on `i`, and the end point on `i - 2`:

```js
let c = document.querySelector('canvas');
let context = c.getContext('2d');
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.lineCap = 'round';
function line(xa, ya, xb, yb) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(xa, ya);
    context.lineTo(xb, yb);
    context.stroke();
}
(function drawLine(i){
    line(155 + (57 - i) / 2, i, 155 + (57 - (i - 2)) / 2, (i - 2));
    line(245 - (57 - i) / 2, i, 245 - (57 - (i - 2)) / 2, (i - 2));
    if (i > 35) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            drawLine(i-2);
        }, 10);
    }
})(57);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Canvas.js](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/#canvasjs):

```js
const canvas = new Canvas('my-canvas', 200, 200).start();

const line1 = new Canvas.Line({
  from: {
    x: 50,
    y: 70
  },
  to: {
    x: 60,
    y: 30
  },
  lineWidth: 7,
  lineCap: 'round',
  lineLength: 0.1
});

canvas.addElement(line1);

line1.animate('lineLength', {lineLength: 1, duration: 500});

const line2 = new Canvas.Line({
  from: {
    x: 90,
    y: 70
  },
  to: {
    x: 80,
    y: 30
  },
  lineWidth: 7,
  lineCap: 'round',
  lineLength: 0.1
});

canvas.addElement(line2);

line2.animate('lineLength', {lineLength: 1, duration: 500});
```

```html
<script src="https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/Canvas.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using line dash to animate along paths.

A simple way to animate along any path is to use the line dash and line dash offset.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineCap = 'round';


function drawLines(){
   function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2){
      ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
      ctx.lineTo(x2,y2); 
   }
   drawLine(10,10,490,90);
   drawLine(10,190,490,110);
}

var lineLength = 30; // pixels
var distanceBetween = 400;
var lineSpeed = 300;  //pixels per second
ctx.setLineDash([lineLength, distanceBetween]); 

function animateLines(time){
    ctx.lineDashOffset = -time * lineSpeed / 1000;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function loop(time){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    drawLines();
    animateLines(time);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=200></canvas>
```